# How to listen to a button getting enabled or disabled in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

I have a button in SWT and I want to add a listener so that whenever the button goes enabled or disabled, I can print something.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 3):

SWT does not provide notifications for enablement changes.

If such notifications are actually necessary, the code that calls `setEnabled()` needs to send these notifications.